# Simplify an associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp

I'm hitting an api built using CakePHP. Cake returns its objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "Note": {
            "id": "1",
            "clas": "test",
            "obj_id": null,
            "note": "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "Note": {
            "id": "2",
            "clas": "another",
            "obj_id": null,
            "note": "another"
        }
    }
]
```

What I want to do is take that result and basically get rid of the keys. Something like this:

```
[
    {
            "id": "1",
            "clas": "test",
            "obj_id": null,
            "note": "test"
    },
    {
            "id": "2",
            "clas": "another",
            "obj_id": null,
            "note": "another"
    }
]
```

I'm basically just trying to make it easier to reference this in Angular. I need to do this on the client side. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting that result? I mean, before getting the JSON. Maybe you can use Hash::extract()

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla "I need to do this on the client side." :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could refactor it like so:

```
var json = '[{"Note":{"id":"1","clas":"test","obj_id":null,"note":"test"}},{"Note":{"id":"2","clas":"another","obj_id":null,"note":"another"}}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    arr.push(obj[i].Note);
}
```

Working example [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/epd83/)

(**Note** also that if your key value 'Note' isn't always the same, this will change dramatically. It's likely that 'Note' isn't going to be the same in each instance either; that would generate an improperly keyed object. Alternatively, if you always need the first object in the array, you could use `obj[i][0]` instead).

(**More note** if you're using cakephp, this would be much easier done using [`Hash::`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html), but if you need to do it client side, this is the solution).

Comment: Thanks r3mus you're totally right. I can't guarantee that I will have key every time. I'm going to kick this back over the fence to the backend guys and see if I can't get them to make my life easier with hash. Your solutions totally works in this instance though.

Comment: Yep ;) I have to deal with that kind of thing all the time, makes a lot more sense to refactor on the back end. But regardless, if you have to do it this way, you can.